Two non finite polynomial equations with the same solutions
If $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...=0$ and $b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+...=0$ be two equations such that their solutions are same then can it be said that
$\frac{a_0}{b_0}=\frac{a_1}{b_1}=\frac{a_2}{b_2}=\ldots$?
Where $a_i$ and $b_i$ ($i=0,1,2,...$) are non zero
The query is regarding non finite polynomials. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

By definition, there are not "infinite" polynomials. You need necessarily to have $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n=0$ with $a_n\lt\infty$

My question is regarding infinite polynomial. What's happens in this case. What can be said in this case

As a side note, infinite-degree polynomials are called formal series.

... or "entire functions" if you want to be able to ask whether any given  number $x$ is a solution of $a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots = 0$.

No, it can't. For instance, $f(x)=\sin x+\cos x$ and $g(x)=e^{x^2}(\sin x + \cos x)$ have the same zeros but the coefficients of their power series expansions do not satisfy $\frac{a_i}{b_i}=\frac{a_j}{b_j}$ for all $i\neq j$.

Yes. Going through it
